# Compiling TypeScript into Javascript in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

How do I compile my TypeScript files in Visual Studio 2015?

I have an app.ts that is being compiled into app.js when the project is built, but I am developing more TypeScript files - such as AngularJS controllers - that are not being compiled.

I thought it might be about including references in my app.ts to the other TypeScript files but that doesn't work.

Any ideas? I've Googled but I guess it's too new for such things to be on the interweb.

---

Comment: Haven't played yet with VS2015, but as far as I remember VS doesn't come with a built-in TypeScript compiler, I guess you need to install some extension or use other build tools like Grunt/Gulp

Comment: Nope, it does come with a TypeScript compiler. I was being an idiot. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the Javascript was in fact being generated, but was not included in the project so I didn't see it. All working now.

Comment: you can also define a **tsconfig.json** file in the root of your project to configure the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Check the checkbox “Compile TypeScipt on Build” in the Build properties of your ASP.NET Core project, for ASP.NET classic search for the tab "Typescript build" in the properties of the MVC project.
2) You can use ["tsc"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) from the command line.

You can add a tsconfig.ts file into the folder that contains your typescripts.
Here is an example of such a config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false  
},  
"compileOnSave": true
}
```